# How can I get deprecated warnings in GraphQL query response

Tags: node.js, graphql, deprecated, apollo-server, deprecation-warning

I need to get deprecated warnings in GraphQL query response as in the below image (inside extensions):

[image]

Currently, once I added `@deprecated` to the Type definition, I do not get the `"extensions"` parameter in the response.

```
type Post {
    title: String
    isPublished: Boolean @deprecated(reason: "no longer supported")
}
```

How I can achieve this with NodeJS `apollo-server`